# Programmatically Add Visual State Setter in Code-Behind

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm in the process of an 8.1 Universal conversion to UWP. I have some code in the code-behind that creates potentially hundreds of nodes in a stack panel programmatically from view model data. I'm trying to add some visual responsive rules to some of these nodes.

The pattern I'm using is basically:

```
foreach (var item in ViewModel.items)
{
    var fooStackPanel = CreateItemRowStackPanel();

    fooStackPanel.Children.Add(CreateItemImage(item.ProductUrl));
    fooStackPanel.Children.Add(CreateItemNameTextBlock(item.Name));
    // ...

    LayoutGrid.Children.Add(fooStackPanel);
}
```

Somewhere in there I want to add a responsive rules to specific nodes.

Here's how what I want to do would look in XAML, but I need to do these setters within the code behind. How do I do so?

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="WindowStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="NarrowState">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>

            <VisualState.Setters>
                <!-- How do I add these programmatically in the code behind? -->
                <Setter Target="Item1Image.Visibility" 
                        Value="Collapsed" />
                <Setter Target="Item2Image.Visibility" 
                        Value="Collapsed" />
                <!-- ... -->
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Comment: Ok.  What is your question?

Comment: How do I add these programmatically in the code behind?

Comment: Isn't it much easier to use a ListView with DataTemplate and bind the Visibility of the image?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Bart said it's far more easier to bind the visibility, but if that's not working for you for some reason you can add `VisualState` `Setters` from codebehind this way:

1) Create a new visual state group

`var vsg = new VisualStateGroup();`

2) Create your states

`var vs = new VisualState()`

You can't name it, but it's not necessary to do so. If you really have to (eg. you want to manually use `GoToState`, you can do 
`var vs = (VisualState) XamlReader.Load($"<VisualState x:Name=\"{*yournameinline*}\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" xmlns:x=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml\" />");`.

3) Add your statetriggers:

`vs.StateTriggers.Add(new AdaptiveTrigger
 {
     MinWindowWidth = 0.0
 });`

4) Add your setters:

```
vs.Setters.Add(new Setter
    {
    Target = new TargetPropertyPath
        {
            Path = new PropertyPath("(Image.Visibility)"),
            Target = *yourimage*
        },
    Value = Visibility.Collapsed
});
```

5) Grab the control's visual state groups and add everything:

`vsg.States.Add(vs);`

`VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(*yourcontrol*).Add(vsg)`

Comment: How are you supposed to set the state without using GoToState?

Comment: @PeterMoore with `VisualStateTriggers`